# Colon character ":" in some file names under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, filenames

I've been revisiting my old hard drive where I backed up my files long ago. I used Ubuntu back then and had no troubles creating files with a ':' (colon) character in their names. Now, however, I cannot access it, nor move or delete, even from terminal.

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to rename this file under Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Ubuntu (or other Linux) LIVE-CD (from CD or USB).